# A bug in copy&paste of plain text

Tags: front-end, notebooks, string-manipulation, formatting

My mathematica version is 12.2 and OS is windows 10.

1. In a new .nb document
2. Write a string "abc" in the first cell
3. Right mouse click on the first cell bracket
4. click copy as - plain text
5. ctrl+v (paste) at the next cell(=second cell)
6. In 95% case, paste fails and I get an error message.
7. But in 5% case, paste succeed and error message doesn't show up.

I investigated this phenomenon with a clipboard tool,
and concluded that from the time the clipboard was formed, there was an error.
If the first component is 'Mathematica cells', it is doomed to fail.
If the first component is 'CF_unicodetext', then it is doomed to succeed.

The first GIF shows a typical fail case.

[image]

The second GIF shows many fail cases and one success case.
(The cursor moves back and forth with the joy of success)

[image]

I think this is a bug. (In the world of programming or software, usually 95% case is ok and bug occurs at 5%. But this time, 5% case is ok and bug occurs at 95%)

PS) In some state, a little surprisingly, I keep getting success only, never get fail.
But I don't know how to get to that state.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

The probelm was solved by @ihojnicki, as commented below. I was testing a clipboard tool - it was the cause. Funnily I used another clipboard tool to inspect what was going on, and seems it made things worse.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out your Mathematica version. I did follow your instructions on version 13.0.1 and it works fine multiple times.

Comment: Are you using an external clipboard history tool?  That looks/acts like something has locked the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you! @ihojnicki, that was the reason! I was testing clipboard tools. After turning them off, there is no such bug.

Comment: Please read the [tag:bugs] tag info. The tag is applied by the community, once there is a consensus that it is a bug.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in the comments. Moreover the issue was not related to Mathematica.

Comment: I have experienced similar behavior with Mathematica 13 (and perhaps earler) under macOS when I have the "Copy Less 2" clipboard utility app open.

Comment: Thank you, I'll not add the bugs tag, then.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It seems like it would be useful for someone in the future facing the same problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s caused by a third party tool

Comment: @JasonB I thought it pretty clear why it was closed: it's not about Mathematica. Sometimes, when I switch my laptop between an HD and a 4k external monitors, at work vs at home, I get odd font sizing issues in Mathematica. It turns out that other programs have that issue as well (Adobe Acrobat being one). Would that be an appropriate behavior to bring up in this forum? I would say not, because the behavior is external to MMA. By the same token, i found this question off topic as well.

Comment: I think this question very clearly is about Mathematica, specifically how it interacts with other software a user might have installed.  I would even call that ugly XML message a bug in Mathematica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @ihojnicki in the comments, this behavior is most likely caused by using an external clipboard history tool.  For some reason Mathematica is unable to work with these tools, and you get that ugly XML message.